# Jbehave Test configuration and test reporting not working as expected

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, jbehave

I am using Jbehave to test some API's. I configured my stories but when i run the configuartion file, i get the following output:

```
Reports view generated with 0 stories (of which 0 pending) containing 0 scenarios (of which 0 pending)
```

I assumed that my configuration worked fine, and tried to run my whole test package, but it returned an output saying

```
No tests found in the package "com.example.prederiq.PrederaAiq"
```

However, when i ran my PrederaAiqApplicationTests.java file containing the test cases, all the tests passed but no console report or html report was returned to me. I have attached all the concerned files in my test package below and also the project structure below, please help me sort this out

*Project Structure:*

[image]

My Configuration file:

```
public class StoryConfiguration extends JUnitStories {

    @Override
    public Configuration configuration() {
        return new MostUsefulConfiguration().useStoryLoader(new LoadFromClasspath(this.getClass())).useStoryReporterBuilder(new StoryReporterBuilder().withCodeLocation(CodeLocations.codeLocationFromClass(this.getClass())).withDefaultFormats().withFormats(StoryReporterBuilder.Format.CONSOLE, StoryReporterBuilder.Format.HTML));
    }

    @Override
    public InjectableStepsFactory stepsFactory() {
        return new InstanceStepsFactory(configuration(),new PrederaAiqApplicationTests());
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> storyPaths() {
        String codeLoc = codeLocationFromClass(this.getClass()).getFile();
        return new StoryFinder().findPaths(codeLoc, asList("**/test*.story"),asList(""),"file"+codeLoc);
    }
}
```

test.story file:

```
Given: An authorised URL
When: A GET req is made
Then: 200 status code is returned

Given:Unauthorised link
When:GET req is made
Then: 401 status code is returned

Given: An authorised URL.
When: A GET req is made to it
Then: application type is json

Given: An authorised URL.
When: A GET req is made to it
Then: output same as that in documentation
```

PrederaAiqApplicationsTest file:

```
class PrederaAiqApplicationTests {
    String contentType;
    String uri = "https://sandbox.predera.com/aiq/api/projects";
    WireMockServer wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(wireMockConfig().dynamicPort().dynamicHttpsPort());
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    String auth = "Bearer " + "eyJraWQiOiJndE1YKzh2bVBaNnk0NElmdllGNDZqVDlvRG5RZWxoeUg4d1JjMVwvWkdBND0iLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.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.pcp4KY0HzcAtWIgFfoX5sRwJccQ4GizlbBqoh5GuaoRMkvPrzBtLRf1AwC2tsL8cFDni6whxhClSgW_w1cDQZUUUHQ82svDxiSBLLft1ZAg9VVOlJ1AkKbaZDcoA-4wVAZBdzmmuCiwhNerP9Ask2DiP0slAADwzNMfhlhvlqcqdWbZyEreHMuUkVkGVdSUDK933TRKkKP-x62PTsize6oi-mApmeZY3Qr5AcGHHW3frZE-XuYlLaJzDZH5yJv7qA7pkQ5c05LPlZdWrwTelEdx8GLRKRs-fFnwIquOLkWceqSyYuz3gFalXOG3xfZtVIozNfVfocZzXN54ul7_B-g";
    int status = 0;
    JSONArray array;
    HttpUriRequest httpUriRequest;
    @Test
    @Given("An authorised URL")
    void test(){
        httpUriRequest = RequestBuilder.get().setUri(uri).setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION,auth).build();
    }
    @When("A GET req is made")
    void testGet() throws IOException {
        HttpResponse response =httpClient.execute(httpUriRequest);
        status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    }
    @Then("200 status code is returned")
    void test200() {
        assertEquals(200,status);
    }

    @Test
    @Given("Unauthorised link")
    void test2() {
        httpUriRequest = RequestBuilder.get().setUri(uri).build();
    }
    @When("GET req is made")
    void get2() throws IOException {
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpUriRequest);
        status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    }
    @Then("401 status code is returned")
    void statusTest2(){
        assertEquals(401,status);
    }
    @Test
    @Given("An authorised URL.")
    void test3(){
        httpUriRequest = RequestBuilder.get().setUri(uri).setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION,auth).build();
    }
    @When("A GET req is made to it")
    void getTest3() throws IOException {
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpUriRequest);
        contentType = String.valueOf(response.getEntity().getContentType());
    }
    @Then("application type is json")
    void content(){
        assertEquals("application/json",contentType);
    }
    @Test
    @Given("An authorised URL.")
    void test4(){
        httpUriRequest = RequestBuilder.get().setUri(uri).setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION,auth).build();
    }
    @When("A GET req is made to it")
    void testGet4() throws IOException, ParseException {
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpUriRequest);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(entity.getContent());
        String content = "";
        while(scanner.hasNext()){
            content += scanner.nextLine();
        }
        scanner.close();
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        array = (JSONArray) parser.parse(content);
    }
    @Then("output same as that in documentation")
    void content2(){
        assertEquals("[{\"owner\":\"ppallavalli@umass.edu\",\"name\":\"churn-juyma\",\"description\":\"Customer Churn Example\",\"last_modified_date\":\"2021-06-09T17:38:06.048Z\",\"id\":\"a-443018111\",\"created_date\":\"2021-06-09T17:38:06.048Z\",\"last_modified_by\":\"ppallavalli@umass.edu\",\"created_by\":\"ppallavalli@umass.edu\",\"users\":[\"ppallavalli@umass.edu\"]}]",array.toString());
    }
}
```

Pom.xml:

```
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example.prederiq</groupId>
    <artifactId>PrederaAiq</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>PrederaAiq</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbehave-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
            <artifactId>wiremock-jre8</artifactId>
            <version>2.28.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>
                        --illegal-access=permit
                    </argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```